# how to use bean values passed from a servlet in jsp file

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, javabeans

I passed bean object from a servlet to a jsp file and want to use bean value as follows but it throws runtime error. What am I doing wrong?

```
 <%@ page import = "beans.UserInfo" %>
 <%
   UserInfo userInfo = (UserInfo)session.getAttribute("userInfo");
   String userName = userInfo.getUserName();
 %>
```

Exeption is as follows:

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:491)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspService(Login_jsp.java:60)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.28 logs.

Comment: You *should* include exception stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code in `doPost` or `doGet` to should be as follows where you're constructing `beans.UserInfo` and issue `forward` method of `Dispatcher`.

```
 bean.UserInfo info=new bean.UserInfo();
 //set the bean properties
 session.setAttribute("userInfo",info);
 request.getRequestDispatcher("/your_page.jsp")
    .forward(request,response);
```

Comment: i did as you said but the above null pointer exception is thrown again. i have made sure in my servlet that the bean values are never null so why is the page throwing exception